# Error in Oracle SQL developer "table or view doesnot exist"

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I am trying to create a table and an index on it in Oracle SQL developer, but I keep getting the error:

> Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

My statements:

```
CREATE TABLE TAB_ATTRIBUTES_OF_RELATIONSHIP
(
REL_NAME                VARCHAR(15) not null,
ATTR_NAME             VARCHAR(15) not null, 
ATTREL_DATATYPE  VARCHAR(15) not null, 
ATTREL_DOMAIN     VARCHAR(20),

constraint PK_ATTRIBUTES_OF_RELATIONSHIP primary key (REL_Name, ATTR_NAME),
constraint FK_ATTRIBUTES_OF_RELATIONSHIP foreign key (REL_NAME)
            references RELATIONSHIPS (REL_NAME)
constraint FK_ATTRIBUTES_OF_RELATIONSHIP foreign key (ATTR_NAME)
            references ATTRIBUTES (ATTR_NAME),
);

/* Index: IDX_ATTRIBUTES_OF_RELATIONSHIP    */

Create index IDX_ATTRIBUTES_OF_RELATIONSHIP_FK on Tab_ATTRIBUTES_OF_RELATIONSHIP

(
ATTR_NAME ASC
);
```

Comment: Can you access tables RELATIONSHIPS and ATTRIBUTES from the same SQL developer session?

Comment: Simplify the code to narrow down the problem.  I assume only one of the statements is throwing an error, so remove the unnecessary statement.  Then start removing columns, constraints, etc., until the statement is as small as possible and still throws an error.  Also, the error message should normally display or highlight the relevant line and column number, that can also help you focus on the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the `CREATE TABLE` statement. You should pay attention where you place the commas, and maybe try to execute the script step by step

Here's a corrected version of your table creation statement

```
CREATE TABLE TAB_ATTRIBUTES_OF_RELATIONSHIP
(
REL_NAME                VARCHAR(15) not null,
ATTR_NAME             VARCHAR(15) not null, 
ATTREL_DATATYPE  VARCHAR(15) not null, 
ATTREL_DOMAIN     VARCHAR(20),
constraint PK_ATTRIBUTES_OF_RELATIONSHIP primary key (REL_Name, ATTR_NAME),
constraint FK_ATTRIBUTES_OF_RELATIONSHIP foreign key (REL_NAME)
            references RELATIONSHIPS (REL_NAME),
constraint FK_ATTRIBUTES_OF_RELATIONSHIP foreign key (ATTR_NAME)
            references ATTRIBUTES (ATTR_NAME)
);
```